# Which mode to use edit existing deck.gl polygons using nebula.gl?

Tags: javascript, npm, geojson, deck.gl

I'm trying to implement a basic example to edit GeoJSON polygon features using *deck.gl*. Layter I need to edit a lot of data, so I want to use [nebula.gl](https://nebula.gl/), specifically [EditableGeoJsonLayer](https://nebula.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/editable-geojson-layer).

My problem basically is that `ModifyMode` adds additional features instead of editing existing polygons:

```
onClick: (event) => {
    selectedFeatureIndex = event.object ? [event.index] : [];
    console.log(event.object, selectedFeatureIndex);

    deck.setProps({
      layers: [
        new EditableGeoJsonLayer({
          id: "geojson-layer",
          data: COUNTRIES,
          pickable: true,
          pickingRadius: 10,
          autoHighlight: true,
          mode: ModifyMode,
          selectedFeatureIndexes: selectedFeatureIndexes,
        }),
      ],
    });
  },
```

The whole example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nebula-gl-edit-polygon-nttgjt?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.mjs).

I'm just starting with nebula and have a problem of understanding the [different modes](https://nebula.gl/docs/api-reference/modes/overview) which can be used with `EditableGeoJsonLayer`.

Just as a note, for now I use plain Javascript. I want to avoid *React*, as my app where I want to integrate it, runs on *vue.js*.

Comment: I would recommend https://nebula.gl/geojson-editor/ as a learning resource. Play around with the app and look at the code. It looks like the basemap is broken, and the app is not loading properly anymore though ️. So I'd suggest closing the nebula.gl repo and running it locally. There's a lot of stuff that isn't documented.

Comment: Oh I also made https://geojsons.com/ (open source), which uses React, deck.gl and nebula.gl. However, it doesn't demonstate all the features of nebula.